# Purchased AWS reserved instance in wrong region

Tags: amazon-web-services

I purchased AWS reserved instance by mistake in Mumbai Region. actually, I need that in N.virginia region.

I contact AWS support center and they told "switching region of AWS reserved instance is not possible"

Is there any way to switch region? Please help.

Comment: Switching is indeed not possible, but if you really did make the purchase by mistake, you need to provide AWS Support with that information, because "changing" the region isn't technically what you want to do -- what you really want is to cancel/undo your mistake and make a new purchase -- so if you did not ask for help doing specifically that, you should probably try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have done payment of your reserved instance then you are unlucky. now you have only one option **Sell your reserved instance in AWS marketplace**.

But If you till not done payment then you lucky, I suggest don't do payment till next billing cycle. AWS by default cancel your reserved instance if you don't do payment after the end of the month.